# VS2010 CSS auto formatting not working

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS2010 and I'm working on a Style .css file
I wanted to auto format but it doesn't work... why?
the key command is ctrl+k, ctrl+f
it says:
they key combination (ctrl+k, ctrl+f) is bound to command (format Selection) which is not currently available.

what's the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D. Works for me in Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express 2010.

Comment: it works thanks. I don't have the express edition though, I have the professional one